# Mobile Safari Jailbreak Tweak Development

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, jailbreak

I can't seem to find an online tutorial that explains how to develop a jailbreak tweak for mobile safari. Can someone provide me with any type of resources to learn how to develop a mobile safari tweak? The source code for any mobile safari tweaks also would be a good resource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "online resources for developer tweaks for Mobile Safari". There also aren't any open source projects or public code snippets that I know of that deal with Mobile Safari.

You will need to tear apart the headers of Mobile Safari, and there are a ton of them!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question, are there any book out there specifically written for learn how to write a jailbreak tweak? The books recommended in Cydia seems too old. I tried using theos but need more examples to learn more. Thanks.

Comment: No newer books that I know of. Try searching Github, a lot of the jailbreak devs put their code on there.

Comment: Thanks. I will search through the GitHub. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Like the others were saying, there is not much information available how to tweak MobileSafari.
You basically will have to do all the work yourself. 
But keep in mind that tweaking MobileSafari is a big hassle. Not only is it complicated but Apple has been changing a lot in every version. 
A general resource about tweak development is http://iphonedevwiki.net/

PS: I'm the dev of FullScreen for Safari ;) so you can trust me that tweaking it can be extremely annoying